# Determine if system clock is in 12 or 24 hour clock format: Windows 7, C++11

Tags: c++11, windows-7-x64, clock, time-format

Is it possible to determine if the system clock is in either 12 or 24 hour format from a Windows 7, C++11 application?

Many Thanks!

Comment: 12-24 is related to the system locale, not the clock. (i.e, related to how you *display* time, not how you measure it). Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I think you have to retrieve `LOCALE_STIMEFORMAT` using GetLocaleInfoEx() and parse it to see whether it has H or h.